# C# How to use the style for control in another class?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's my code for the style. I would like to use it for my panel
How could I apply it in the other class?

```
public class ExtendedPanel : Panel
    {
        private const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
        public ExtendedPanel()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(this.opacity * 255 / 100, this.BackColor)))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
            }
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
```

My Main Class where I will apply this style:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExtendedPanel ds = new ExtendedPanel();
        panel3= ds;



    }
}
```

Is there a quick solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do?  It's not clear.  So you have an instance of your `ExtendedPanel` class: `ds`.  What are you hoping to do with it?  What is it you need us to help you with?

Comment: Use the designer to delete panel3 and then add your new panel.

Comment: I want to apply the Class Extended panel to my panel3.
How can i do that? 
I mean extended panel is a style. But the thing i want to happen is to apply it in my panel3 in the main class

Comment: You don't seem to understand how control inheritance works.  Never use the code you posted, it leaks the existing panel3 object for the life of the app since it got never disposed.  Instead, ensure your project is built.  Open the designer for the form.  Delete the existing panel.  And drag+drop your new panel from the top of the toolbox.